# django - a good step by step example on how to save images

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-forms, django-views

Can anybody provide a good step by step example on how to save images in django? Like what goes in models.py, views.py, forms.py, template etc.? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two should help:

- [dynamic upload of paths in django](http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/25/dynamic-upload-paths-in-django/) - this even lets the client specify where to upload the image
- [How to upload images in django](http://solutions.treypiepmeier.com/2007/02/27/howto-upload-images-in-django/)